# Transaction error: An unknown error has occurred During In App Purchased

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

i am implementing the in app purchased in my app, i have created the test user, the App ID, Distribution Profile, Development Profile, and also enable the in App Purchased in the App, But does not upload the binaries. I have correctly used the App ID. but when i test the app on the simulator using the Store kit, it gives the following error "Transaction error: An unknown error has occurred, the transaction has been canceled by the user, but the user does not Canceled the Transaction.

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
{
    switch (transaction.transactionState)
    {
        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
            [self completeTransaction:transaction];
            break;
        case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
            [self failedTransaction:transaction];
            break;
        case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
            [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

}

Transaction fails and called the method  [self failedTransaction:transaction];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your device is jailbroken then StoreKit will not work on it. Try testing InAppPurchase on a device which is not jailbroken